# NullpointerException in Service

Tags: android, service

I have a little problem in service (android).
             In my code what i am doing exactly...first i send data through intent to service.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), External.class);
i.putExtra("data",data);
i.setAction(External.ACTION_PLAY);
getApplicationContext().startService(i);
```

Then in method `onStartCommand()` i receive that data.

```
Bundle b=i.getExtras();
data=i.getStringExtra("data");
```

So in notificationbar with action_play by `onPlay()` method we get actual data.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I get your message"+ data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Then, when i again try to receive that data by with acton_pause by `onPause()` method i get null, i mean" I get your message null." every time i get that, i initialize every thing make them all static one by one and together but i got null.i am putting my initialization code here ,check that and help me to solve it......

In activity

```
private static  String data="music is mine";
```

In External service

```
private static String data="";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From information you attached to the problem I could not reproduce an issue. Maybe you are using wrong intent or have more "data" variables?